# How I can do optional unwrapping this swiftUI identifiable data?

Tags: listview, swiftui, option-type

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nGFs.jpg)

Could you check my attached picture?

I want to use the optional data with unwrapping.

What I want to do is that after unwrap the data, I will make ListView with the item in data.

But, I don't know how I can use the optional data for list view.

Thank you!

Comment: You are missing the second half of the ForEach view - try `ForEach(dataModel.items) { item in /* ... */ }`

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff. All your code should be included in the question as code not an image

Comment: You can also try using `ForEach(dataModel.items, id: \.id) { item in }`